# Ruby: JSON.parse returns undefined method `bytesize' for

Tags: ruby, json, sinatra

```
response = Typhoeus::Request.get("http://localhost:3000/api/api_email/#{@api_id}.json")
    JSON.parse(response.body)
```

The response is a JSON object but I get an error when trying to parse it.

```
undefined method `bytesize' for
```

I want to get access to the JSON object.

Error:

```
NoMethodError at /api/v1/a71040739d6cc50e89aff56601af67/2011-10-1
undefined method `bytesize' for {"xpto"=>{"email

"=>"test@gmail.com"}}:Hash

file: utils.rb location: bytesize line: 239
```

BacktracE:

```
/Users/donald/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in service
      si.service(req, res)
/Users/donald/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in run
          server.service(req, res)
/Users/donald/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb in block in start_thread
          block ? block.call(sock) : run(sock)
```

This is how is being generated:

```
 @api_id = params[:api_id]
 @bucket = Bucket.where(:api => @api_id)
 respond_with(@bucket, :only => [:email])
```

The .json file being returned contains:

```
[{"xpto":{"email":"test@gmail.com"}}]
```

Comment: It would help if you'd show the JSON you are generating/receiving, at least the section referencing `bytesize`. Also, the formatting is of the examples is hard to read. Please try to preserve the output exactly as it is displayed on your console.

Comment: The .json file has: [{"xpto":{"email":"test@gmail.com"}}]

Comment: Also, please reedit your question and add the information there rather than interspersed in comments throughout the page. It really helps keep all the pertinent information in one place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's weird, as it seems that the response.body is already a Hash! (i.e. parsed JSON string), or, maybe you're seeing this in your webrick's log, and thus the problem is with *generating* the JSON response, rather than parsing it. The backtrace doesn't make sense :(

Comment: I have edited with how the response is being generated. I cant' access any field of the json I get. However, if I print response.body I have the JSON correctly, shouldn't I be able to access response.body["email"] ?

Comment: Can you try to do puts response.body.class.to_s and puts response.body.inspect . Thanks. And regarding your question - no, but response.body['xpto']['email'] may work.

Comment: The first one returns String, the second "[{\"xpto\":{\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\"}}]"

Comment: response.body['xpto']['email'] is empty

Comment: Shouldn't the JSON have "=>" instead of ":" ?

Comment: In which file and line the original exception is raised?

Comment: It says, that it's a string. So I'm curious, where the exception is raised, and which hash it is referring to.

Comment: httpserver.rb in service
      si.service(req, res) line 111

Comment: oh! I know what's going on here. Your JSON.parse is the last line in the method, and it tries to use it as a response body! So actually the JSON.parse succeeded

Comment: Save my day, I was parsing the Hash response. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is probably compatibility issue. You will probably not have that problem if you are using ruby1.9, but if you are using other versions/implementations such as ruby 1.8, or IronRuby, `String#bytesize` might not be defined.

Comment: I am using ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-darwin10.6.0]. Should this work?

Comment: I see. Then it's something else. Can you post the error message with some more information including backtrace?

Comment: @donald What comes after `undefined method bytesize for`?